# How to clone Anchor Program with IDL

Tags: anchor, idl

If I have an Anchor IDL json, is it possible to generate an Anchor program (Rust) script with it?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, no. You'll also need to clone the program executable from the chain. For example, if the program address is `ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL`, you'll need to do:

```
$ solana program dump ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL program.so
Wrote program to atoken.so
$ solana program deploy program.so
Program Id: PzZM4jv8R8MMWwx9QRep9o78eSUhipUQ4j8LBE9gAq8
```

Note that this may not work as expected, since some programs hard-code the expected address of the program when checking ownership or deriving PDAs. In our example, that means that `ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL` is hardcoded somewhere in the executable.